# Play Framework 2.3 Java : FileNotFoundException when specifying configuration file

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

It's pretty simple : I'm trying to start my Play application in production on my server. After `./activator clean compile stage`, I use the following command (when in application directory) :

```
./activator "start -Dconfig.file=/srv/play-apps/prudentia/conf/prod.conf -Dhttp.port=9035"
```

This fail with this Exception :

```
Configuration error: Configuration error["/srv/play-apps/prudentia/conf/prod.conf" : java.io.FileNotFoundException: "/srv/play-apps/prudentia/conf/prod.conf"  (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)]
```

The file exists, the exception is thrown even when I put the 777 rights on the file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the way I started my app was wrong : I have to use the binary created by the `stage` command :

```
target/universal/stage/bin/prudentia -Dconfig.file=/srv/play-apps/prudentia/conf/prod.conf -Dhttp.port=9035
```

This works fine.